# Is there anyway to use an embedded JSON if request fails?

Tags: ios, json, restkit, restkit-0.20, seeding

When using RestKit, can I embed in my app a service response (as a JSON file) so when the app fails (offline use) or the web service fails (server fails or just plane mode)? can I use that embedded data?
I would like to reuse the mapping and the request so it's easier to program the UI.
Can RestKit do that?
Any idea or suggestion? Reading the docs or issues I don't see anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not really do this with JSON, you should use a seed to your Core Data database.

If you aren't using Core Data or you want to use JSON then you can create a new object manager, with the same mappings, and with a base URL which is a file URL (pointing to your folder containing your JSON files on disk) to load and process them.

Comment: Interesting. I never thought about a manager pointing to a local file.